Button goes outside of its container in bootstrap 5, what should I do?
here's the html I used for the code, but the button keeps going out of the parent div container in all sizes.
<header class="header">
  <div class="hero text-white pt-7">
    <div class="container-xl">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div class="image-container mb-5 px-4">
            <img src="images/somephoto.jpeg" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div
            class="text-container p-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center h-100 mb-5"
          >
            <h1 class="display-3 fw-bold">Welcom to My Website</h1>
            <p class="lead">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Est ex tempora 
            </p>

            <!-- Form -->
            <div class="form-container text-center">
              <form>
                <div class="row my-4">
                  <input
                    type="email"
                    class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-5"
                   placeholder="Email Address"
                  />
                </div>
                <div class="row d-grid">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-white">Click Here</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

I tried all types of alignment classes but nothing worked yet.

I think you can use the following correct code
<header class="header">
<div class="hero text-white pt-7">
    <div class="container-xl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="image-container mb-5 px-4">
                    <img src="images/somephoto.jpeg" alt=""
                        class="img-fluid" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div
                    class="text-container p-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center h-100 mb-5">
                    <h1 class="display-3 fw-bold">Welcome to My Website</h1>
                    <p class="lead">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing
                        elit. Est ex
                        tempora
                    </p>

                    <!-- Form -->
                    <div class="form-container text-center">
                        <form>
                            <div class="mb-4">
                                <input type="email"
                                    class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-5"
                                    placeholder="Email Address" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="d-grid">
                                <button
                                    class="btn btn-primary btn-lg text-white">
                                    Click Here
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

I have Removed row class from the button container And Adjusted mb-4 margin:
(to ensure spacing between the input)
